# Issue with Rails 5.2.4 translation method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

The **index** view pushed by the **Scheduler::ProductionJobsController** index method contains the following request to the translation method:

```
  <h2> <%= t('.View') %> </h2>
```

The config\locales\Scheduler\ProductionJob\ **fr_OFS.yml** file (which is current user's language) contains the following entries:

```
# Code for language as declared in i18n configuration
fr_OFS:
  # Considered object from a global view
  ProductionJobs:                          "Flux de production"

  # Considered object from controller's methods. In the controller, the relative path for the term is marked by the point (.)
  scheduler:
    production_jobs:
      index:
        # Columns titles
        Code:                                   "Identifiant"
        Name:                                   "Nom"
        Description:                            "Description"
        Owner:                                  "Responsable"
        Version:                                "Mis à jour le"
        Status:                                 "Statut"
        View:                                   "Voir"
        Delete:                                 "Supprimer"
```

Eventhough this looks trivial, it results in a translation missing error:

```
<h2>
  <span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: fr_OFS.scheduler.production_jobs.index.View">View</span>
</h2>
```

Writing `t('scheduler.production_jobs.index.View')` does not change a thing...

Did I miss something?

Thanks for your help!